# ext4 pointers from in-memory inode

Tags: linux-kernel, ext4

I'm trying to retrieve in a kernel module the direct/indirect etc addresses in an ext4 file system inode. I understand that I need to look into ext_inode_info struct (I do this via container_of using the relevant vfs_inode).
But to which field am I supposed to look into?

Where can I find for example the first direct pointer? I thought it was stored in i_data  array (it is in ext3_inode_info). 
But for an ext4 inode when I examine the first entry in i_data, I get a sector address that is not remotely similar to the real sector holding the address of the first data block.

Any help will be appreciated.

==EDIT==

ok, so I seemed to have understood the basic problem. I have an extent-based ext4 file system. Wasn't aware of this change, and that this is enabled by default. So is there a simple way to extract the physical addresses of blocks by offset? I'm trying again as verification to look at the first physical block (logical 0), by looking at the first extent, but I get some gibberish numbers (though consistent and unique for every inode/file, so some progress was made).

Comment: Why? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to gather a trace and some statistics on IO requests to a device, and one of the things I want to show is relation to to file location.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766317/data-pointers-in-inode-data-structure

Comment: I've seen that post. If I understand correctly it refers to the on-disk inode (ext4_inode). The in-memory inode (ext4_inode_info) doesn't have the i_block array. It made sense to me that i_data holds it, but fact is - I see that the data in it does not correspond to the relevant disk locations.